# Store billions of rows with no relation

Tags: linux, database, mysql, mongodb, nosql

I'm going to receive a large group of CSV files daily. Additionally I have 1 billion records of data (from those CSV files) but its not a fixed number (1b records daily). They're going to be growing and I need to store them in a DB. Also there are some extra points:

1. There's no update
2. There's no join and relationship
3. Select a bunch of rows and group by
4. Write intensive is so more than read
5. I don't need normalisation

I had a bench between MySQL InnoDB and MyISAM. MyISAM was more better than InnoDB (because I have no normalisation) but MySQL is not a good approach because I have no relation.

I also checked MongoDB but with 50GB of CSV data it used 150Gb of storage!

I know I can use CSV files but I need a database approach. A database has lots of tools (like simple GROUP BY queries) and advantages like updates, bug fixes, security stuff, read and write performance, replication etc.

So I think I need a NoSQL DB which can do distributed write and support above extra points. But I don't know which NoSQL one (ones) is better for me.

I'm using Linux (CentOS).

Comment: What OS does it have run on? What are you willing to pay? Please [edit] your question and take Thomas' comment into account.

Comment: I'm constantly amazed by how badly people read. You were asked several questions and missed one.

Comment: Regardless of what tool you use, you can have some really large single files. Will your OS handle those huge files? Is it a 64-bit OS? This sounds like an interesting project. I wonder how long a select would take on 10 billion records.

Comment: @Bulrush, Yes it's 64. But I think I/O is more slow than database. and some tools can help in a huge bunch of data.

Comment: @Masood. Why do you think a single table database has slower access when you don't even have a single join or relation to another table? Databases are super optimized to filter and select data and no relations mean they are even faster in this case.

Comment: @Bulrush So I think SQL databases focuses on the relation and NoSQL databases focuses on a less relation (or without relation) structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to manage informations like these.

I used PostgreSQL, where you have the advantage of a relational db and Nosql.

You can store in a single record, normalized data, like import data, an id, etc.. and an array, or a json, or even an Hstore.

Plus: it has native compression.

Comment: Thanks but I don't need normalization. PostgreSQL is a relational one as I said  I have no relation.

Comment: @MasoodAfrashteh I understud. You can use Postgresql without normalization. Postgresql support unstructured data. You want to store a single record per CSV line No problem, you can store it raw, or split in an array of text. Or json, This is unstructured data with a real stable database(even faster than mongo on it's own field).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) with the .csv information converted to [HDF5 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Data_Format) probably by Pandas itself.  HDF5 is generally faster for than SQL star schema.

Not itself a database Pandas includes fast searches, selection, reshaping, group by, etc. and can interface with a large number of databases.

Pandas is Free, gratis & Open Source, and is actively maintained. It interfaces with tools like ipython, jupyter, matplotlib, etc., for improved manipulation and visualization of the data.